# Java Scheduling API - specific intervals

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

I am quite new to Java and I'm trying to generate a task that will run in specific time. There are 3 types of schedule:
a) performing every given number of days in a year,
b) performing every given amount of times in a month (from 1 to 10 times in a specific month),
c) performing every given week of a month (a week from 1 to 5 in a month).

The letters from a to c are the choices of schedule.

I tried several things but nothing is working so far.I used a TimerTask, Calendar, and Timer API. My latest effort is below:

```
public class Runner {
public static void runTask(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int second, String choice) {

    Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    startTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, year );
    startTime.set(Calendar.MONTH,month);
    startTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,day);
    startTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    startTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    startTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, second);
    startTime.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    Calendar bStartTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    bStartTime.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);
    bStartTime.set(Calendar.MONTH,month-1);
    bStartTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);
    bStartTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,12);
    bStartTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    bStartTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    bStartTime.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMM dd");
    long timeToEnd = 0;

    if (choice.equals("a")) {
        Timer time = new Timer();

        time.schedule(new SpecificTask(), startTime.getTime(), TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1));

    }
    else if(choice.equals("b")){
        System.out.println("How many times the task should be done in "+year+"."+month);
        int counter = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        counter = sc.nextInt();

        Timer time = new Timer();
        time.schedule(new SpecificTask(), bStartTime.getTime(), TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(30/counter));
        System.out.println("Date of start : " + sdf.format(bStartTime.getTime()));

    }
    else if(choice.equals("c")){
        Timer time = new Timer();
        time.schedule(new SpecificTask(), startTime.getTime(), TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(2));
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("An error has been occured");

    }

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int year,month,day,hour,minute,second;
    String choiceOfSchedule;
    System.out.println("Welcome in The Ultimate Task Scheduler");
    System.out.print("Select a type of schedule: ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    choiceOfSchedule = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Now set the task's starting time: ... ");
    System.out.println(" Set year: ");
    year = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print(" Set month: ");
    month =sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print(" Set day: ");
    day = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print(" Set hour: ");
    hour = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print( " Set minutes: ");
    minute = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print(" Set seconds: ");
    second = sc.nextInt();
    runTask(year,month,day,hour,minute,second,choiceOfSchedule);
```

Comment: one way to go about it is to keep some structure of tasks, and have something that checks if an event needs to fire. then execute whatever logic you need. I am not really sure what you are asking though.

Comment: I just need a good code which allows me to fire specified amount of task in a specified interval. For example, we have a date like today and in April I want to set 8 task gently distributed over time.

Comment: do you have the code written to figure out when the tasks should be executed? once you figure that out the rest shouldnt be too bad. you can use something like quartz or make your own service.

Comment: No, I don't, that is my problem.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: The `Timer` class was supplanted by the sophisticated Executors framework. See the [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) and search Stack Overflow, to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

## Write one scheduling class per scenario

Seems pointless to me to write one method to handle such different scenarios. I would write one class for each scenario. When setting up the scheduling, each kind of task would know which of the scheduler classes to use.

```
public class DaysPerYearScheduler { … }

public class TimesPerMonthScheduler { … }

public class OrdinalWeekPerMonthScheduler { … }
```

As an analogy, you are trying to do the equivalent of a single method on [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) to do addition & subtraction, multiplication & division, and averaging. Doesn’t that seem awkward?

Learn to use the Executor framework that supplanted the `Timer` class. This has been covered many times already on Stack Overflow.

Never use `Calendar`. That terrible class was supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes. Avoid any date-time class outside the `java.time.*` package.